# Failed to load databse information: SAP Crystal Reports ActiveX Designer

Tags: visual-studio-2015, crystal-reports

I am having this issue again and again after applying multiple solutions like update app.config file and many others. As i want to add database fields to report using ADO.Net datasets it give this error message. Screen shot is attached...[image]

Comment: You said you updated your app.config file, but did you add `<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"></startup>` to the configuration element when you updated it?  If that doesn't fix the error then more detail is needed to help further.

Comment: I updated app.config file completely as @R.McMillan told, but VS 2015 still displaying above mentioned error. I have installed SAP crystal report SP26. Is there any compatibility issue of Visual Studio???